# .IllegalStateException on CheckBox

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I am working on a project that require several Media Players and onTouchListener.
I want to add CheckBox and if box is checked, to Loop Mp's. But I am getting this error and I can't see why.
Here is my code:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true) {
                    mp1.setLooping(true);
                    mp2.setLooping(true);
                    mp3.setLooping(true);
                    mp4.setLooping(true);
                    mp5.setLooping(true);
                    mp6.setLooping(true);
                    mp7.setLooping(true);
                    mp8.setLooping(true);
                    mp9.setLooping(true);
                    mp10.setLooping(true);
                    mp11.setLooping(true);
                    mp12.setLooping(true);
                    mp13.setLooping(true);
                    mp14.setLooping(true);
                    mp15.setLooping(true);
                    Toast.makeText(MainClass.this, "Looping On",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    mp1.setLooping(false);
                    mp2.setLooping(false);
                    mp3.setLooping(false);
                    mp4.setLooping(false);
                    mp5.setLooping(false);
                    mp6.setLooping(false);
                    mp7.setLooping(false);
                    mp8.setLooping(false);
                    mp9.setLooping(false);
                    mp10.setLooping(false);
                    mp11.setLooping(false);
                    mp12.setLooping(false);
                    mp13.setLooping(false);
                    mp14.setLooping(false);
                    mp15.setLooping(false);
                    Toast.makeText(MainClass.this, "Looping Off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

And MP:

```
    if (id == R.id.sound5) {
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    pressed = true;
                    mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(MainClass.this, R.raw.item5);
                    mp5.start();
                    sound5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_pressed);
                } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    pressed = false;
                    mp5.stop();
                    mp5.release();
                    sound5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
                }

07-17 15:41:14.272: W/dalvikvm(16742): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a138b0)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setLooping(Native Method)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at soundmaniacs.com.MainClass$1.onCheckedChanged(MainClass.java:96)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:126)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-17 15:41:14.282: E/AndroidRuntime(16742):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 96 is:

```
mp1.setLooping(true);
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Could it be because Mp is not playing?

Comment: MP is created when button is clicked, you can see in code above Logcat

Comment: Oop, sorry. Missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an `IllegalStateException` because you're calling `release()` on the `MediaPlayer` object, which puts it in its *End* state. When a `MediaPlayer` reaches this state, "it can no longer be used and there is no way to bring it back to any other state." This means that calling `setLooping()` on the player will result in the above-mentioned exception. The simplest way to avoid this would be to remove the call to `release()`. If you do want to release the player whenever possible, to keep the resources in use to a minimum, then you'll need make sure that the player is re-instantiated and in a valid state when calling `setLooping()`.

The quoted is from the [docs, here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)